# Trying to create Drag and Drop with PictureBoxes - events don't trigger

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

**EDIT 1/Resolution:**

Okay I found what was missing. I did not set any event handlers.
Now it works with the following

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    pictureBox1.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(pictureBox1_DragEnter);
    pictureBox1.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(pictureBox1_DragDrop);
}
```

So my next question would be....why do I have to set these? Something like a ButtonClick knows exactly where to go...so why wouldn't these other events?

I'm still a little new to C#.

-

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I'm messing around with dragging and dropping images into a picturebox from my computer.

I have a working version of this in VB. So I just translated (as best I could) it all into C#.

My DragEnter event isn't even triggering at all...I'm not sure what I am missing.

I had to change some things because of the C#/VB differences, but it's basically the same code. I feel like I am missing more events or something...I just don't know what.

Even if it does turn out I have some code wrong...my program never even fires DragEnter....if I put a dummy Debug line or MessageBox in that event just to see if it ran.....it never does.

My form load

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    pictureBox1.AllowDrop = true;
    pictureBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    this.AllowDrop = true;

}
```

My DragEnter

```
 private void pictureBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {


        string[] formats = e.Data.GetFormats();

        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
        {

            if (e.KeyState == CtrlMask && CtrlMask == CtrlMask)
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
            }

        }
        else if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
        }
        else if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Rtf))
        {
            if (e.KeyState == CtrlMask && CtrlMask == CtrlMask)
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
            }

        }
    }
```

And my DragDrop..

```
  private void pictureBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {


        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
        {
           var bmp = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;

        }
        else if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            string[] files;
            files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                string Newfile = file.ToLower();
                string[] ImageTypes = { "gif", "jpg", "png", "bmp" };
                string ActualFileExt = "";
                foreach (string FileExtension in ImageTypes)
                {

                    if (Newfile.EndsWith(FileExtension))
                    {
                        ActualFileExt = FileExtension;
                    }

                }

                if (ActualFileExt != "")
                {
                    pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(Newfile);
                }

            }

        }
        else if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Rtf))
        {


        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You had to explicitly add the handlers since you did not use the 'Handles' keyword after your drop/enter methods. Notice the example code in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289508%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) example uses the Handles keyword similar to a button.

Comment: That example is in VB. There is no 'Handles' keyword in C#. Even auto-generated events (double clicking on a control) do not contain 'Handles'. Turns out that all happens in the Designer or manually in your code.